# How to configure subdomain to specific port

Tags: django, apache, nginx, subdomain, linode

I have two projects **1:** is wordpress running on apache (main website thespatio.com/45.33.10.149)
**2:** A Django Application running on Nginx using same IP with 81 port. (45.33.10.149:81). I want to configure above two apps so that when some one hit http://thespatio.com it should show main website and if some hit http://or.thespatio.com it should show my django application. I have seen many fix but none work for me. I tried virtual host like `proxypass`  and `proxy_reverse` but apache stopped working. below are the two virtual hosts conf file

**Main Website settings (conf)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName thespatio.com
    ServerAlias www.thespatio.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Django App (conf)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName or.thespatio.com
    ServerAlias www.thespatio.com
    ProxyPass / http://or.thespatio.com:81/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://or.thespatio.com:81/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**mod_proxy** was not installed. I follow [Install mod_proxy](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu/) tutorial and my both apps working fine.